# SharePoint Workflow to aggregate Historical data from an Append text field

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, workflow

I am working in SharePoint 2013 but SharePoint Designer 2013 is only configured to build workflows on the 2010 platform.

I have created a workflow that allows me to transfer data from an append text field to a hidden field but only for new data forward. I also need this workflow to grab any historical data and include it with the new data added.

Here is what I have so far:

Log[%Current Item:Detailed Description of Incident%]

then Log [%Current Item:Detailed Description of Incident_Hidden%]

then Set Variable: Hidden to [%Current Item:Detailed Description of Incident_Hidden%]

then Set Detailed Description of Incident_Hidden to [%Current Item:Detailed Description of Incident%][%Variable: Hidden%]

then Log [%Current Item:Detailed Description of Incident_Hidden%] to the workflow history list

like I said it works perfectly for any data added to moving forward but I need a step to grab any of the historical data already present.

I need the Historical data as well as the new in order to run reports.

Answer (score 0):

I worked with the above but I was getting an error because of the amount of data being sent out. here is a simpler solution with example.

Append comments and fields using a workflow

Create a field named “Current Comment”
Create a field called “Append Comment”
Create a variable called “CurrentComment”
Create a variable called “Clear”

1st we create a variable to hold the Current Comment
Set Variable: CurrentComment to Current Item: Current Comment

2nd we set the field “Append Comment” to our variable (I am also adding in the built in fields "Modified and Modified By" [%Vaiable”CurrentComment] - ]%Current Item: Current Comment%] – [%Current Item:Modified%] – [%Current Item:Modified By%]

3rd we clear the Current Comment field
Set Variable Clear to Variable Clear

4th we set Current Comment to Variable Clear